# Change the target framework from Client to full in nuget package

Tags: .net, nuget, xdt-transform

For my company I'm creating a nuget package that transforms a vanilla console project to a corporate batch project so we don't have to do this boilerplate actions every time we create a new batch.

For this I need the target framework to be not Profile=Client, which is the default for new Console Application.

Currently I'm looking into `app.config.install.xdt` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime 
      sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
      xdt:Locator="Condition(@sku='.NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client')"
      xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

This however replaces the entire sku attribute. This could become a problem when we change framework version.

Is it possible to only remove the profile=client part?
Or is there maybe a better way altogether to enforce this?